# Rails Active Record query count multiple relations

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a database structured like this:

- Groups has_many Packages
- Packages has_many Rooms
- Rooms has_and_belongs_to_many Clients

Ok. Every room can be 'Quadruple', 'Triple', 'Double', etc. And I can access all the rooms belonging to a Group by doing Group.rooms.

I want to be able to get how many clients per type of room the Group has.

For example:

- Quad: 16 clients
- Double: 10 clients
  *etc.

I managed to get the ammount of Rooms per type, like this:

```
Group.rooms.group('type').count
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE 1 - Models

Quarto.rb (Rooms)

```
class QuartoContratado < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :pacote
    has_and_belongs_to_many :clientes, :join_table => :acomodacoes
```

Pacote.rb (Packages)

```
class Pacote < ActiveRecord::Base        
    belongs_to :grupo
    has_many :passageiros
    has_many :clientes, :through => :passageiros
    has_many :quartos, :class_name => "QuartoContratado"
```

Grupo.rb (Groups)

```
class Grupo < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :pacotes
    has_many :clientes, :through => :pacotes, :conditions => { :pacotes => { :cancelado => false } }
    has_many :quartos, :class_name => "QuartoContratado", :through => :pacotes, :conditions => { :pacotes => { :cancelado => false } }
```

Client.rb (Clients)

```
class Cliente < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :passageiros
    has_many :pacotes, :class_name => "Pacote", :through => :passageiros
    has_many :grupos, :through => :pacotes, :conditions => { :pacotes => { :cancelado => false } }
```

Comment: Go ahead and post all your models so we can see the actual relationships in place.

Comment: I have updated the question with the models @Lumbee

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to get what I wanted... it looks ugly! Any better way to write it?

```
group = Grupo.first
types = group.quartos.group_by { |t| t.type }

types.each do |key, value|
   print "#{key} - "
   c=0
   value.each do |v|
    c= c+v.clientes.count
   end
   puts "#{c} clients"
 end
```